# Why is the deconstructor not automatically being called?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm working on an assignment for school and having some difficulty understanding the `__del__` method. I understand that it is called after all the references to the object are deleted, but I'm not exactly sure how to get to that point. It states that the `__del__` method should be called automatically, but I'm having a rough time even getting the `del()` to automatically call `__del__` as I understand it should.

I've tried to manually call the del method and have tried looking at various sample coding. Something is just not clicking with me for this. The only way I can some-what get it to be called is by using this piece of code at the end:

```
for faq in faqs:
    Faq.__del__(faq)
```

But I know that is not correct.

```
class Faq:
    def __init__(self, question, answer):
        self.question = question
        self.answer = answer
        return

    def print_faq(self):
        print('\nQuestion: {}'.format(self.question))
        print('Answer: {}'.format(self.answer))

    def __del__(self):
        print('\nQuestion: {}'.format(self.question))
        print('FAQ deleted')

faqs = []

faq1 = Faq('Does this work?', 'Yes.')
faqs.append(faq1)
faq2 = Faq('What about now?', 'Still yes.')
faqs.append(faq2)
faq3 = Faq('Should I give up?', 'Nope!')
faqs.append(faq3)

print("FAQ's:")
print('='*30)
for faq in faqs:
    obj = Faq.print_faq(faq)
print()
print('='*30)
```

I expect the code to output the `__del__` print statements to verify the code ran.

Comment: you need to call it like `del faq1`. But, why do you even want to do that?

Comment: It's a required part of method homework assignment and by the sounds of it, it's suppose to occur automatically. Also, when I run `del faq1` nothing occurs and the __del__ isn't called at all.

Comment: That's weird... you can try `del faqs[:]`. anyway, from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__del__): *It is not guaranteed that __del__() methods are called for objects that still exist when the interpreter exits* - and I think that this is what is confusing you that you expect to happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method [`__del__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__del__) is called

> when the instance is about to be destroyed

This happens when there are no more references to it.

> `del x` doesn’t directly call `x.__del__()` — the former decrements the reference count for `x` by one, and the latter is only called when `x`’s reference count reaches zero.

So the reason you don't see the expected prints is because each `Faq` object has 2 references to it:

1. The variable it is assigned to (`faq1`, `faq2` ...)
2. A reference from the list `faqs`

So doing `del faq1` is not enough as this will only leave one last reference from the list. To delete those references too, you can do `del faqs[:]`.

---

As to the code posted here, I am guessing you expect to see the prints because when the program finishes all resources are released. Well that is true, but:

> It is not guaranteed that [`__del__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__del__) methods are called for objects that still exist when the interpreter exits.

Answer (score 0):

You bind `faqN` and `faqs` and you keep these references. You need to destroy bindings.

For example:

```
faq1 = None # del faq1
faq2 = None
faq3 = None
faqs = None # [] or del faqs
```